# How dynamically change the precision of value using {:10.4f}'.format( [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, uncertainty

I have a variable "n" that contains a number of digits that need to be displayed for the value. How to pass the "n" to '{:10.nf}'.format()?

```
import uncertainties
from uncertainties.umath import *

val_err = uncertainties.ufloat(5, 0.01)
result = val_err*2
n=3  #precision value
result='{:10.nf}'.format(result)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
r = 3.1415926
n = 5

template = f"{{:10.{n}f}}"
result = template.format(r)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result='{0:10.{1}f}'.format(result, n)
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Unfortunately for the code where I need to implement it (which is much more complicated then in an example) it gives me an error: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification. But suggestion of bb1 worked.